# mysterious ip scanning my home website

Tags: linux, python, webserver, raspberry-pi

I'm running a small python based webserver for checking my security cameras and temperature.
but today a mysterious ip address scanned my website.
the ip address is chinese..  what security measurments should I take??
what if there is actual php myadmin running on the site?
how do they get hold of my IP address?
(the site runs a a Rasperry pi B.)

log:

```
220.180.238.134 - - [21/Jan/2015 18:00:45] code 404, message File not found
220.180.238.134 - - [21/Jan/2015 18:00:45] "GET /ztzt/ztz/zt.php HTTP/1.1" 404 -
220.180.238.134 - - [21/Jan/2015 18:00:47] code 404, message File not found
220.180.238.134 - - [21/Jan/2015 18:00:47] "GET /phpMyAdmin/scripts/setup.php HT                      TP/1.1" 404 -
220.180.238.134 - - [21/Jan/2015 18:00:48] code 404, message File not found
220.180.238.134 - - [21/Jan/2015 18:00:48] "GET /pma/scripts/setup.php HTTP/1.1"                       404 -
220.180.238.134 - - [21/Jan/2015 18:00:50] code 404, message File not found
220.180.238.134 - - [21/Jan/2015 18:00:50] "GET /myadmin/scripts/setup.php HTTP/                      1.1" 404 -
```

Comment: This question is better suited for security.stackexchange.com

Comment: If it's on the Internet, expect to be scanned.

Comment: These are quite common, if the traffic is not crippling your server nor ISP line then it's not much to worry about. I think the same IP runs scans on my site but it's only about 20-30 per day for me. If PMA was setup on your server then the hacking attempts are merely trying to exploit it. If you do not have PHP installed then you have nothing to worry about. However you might want to harden your webserver and make sure it is only serving files which you deem safe. You definitely don't want some `www.yoursite.com/../../config_details.py` getting leaked.

Comment: @ThatBrazilianGuy They would probably call this question too broad and close it there as well.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to the Internet!  It is very common to see lots of outside attempts to scan your network.  Bot-Nets, script kiddies, the Chinese scan for vulnerabilities in networks looking for more machines to infect or break into.

As for how they got your IP address, well...  there are only 4,294,967,296 IPv4 addresses.  So its fairly easy for them to scan through them.

Make sure you keep your software up to date with the latest security patches.  I wouldnt worry beyond that.  You *can* ask your ISP to block that IP.

If you are really worried, you could close off the web site and set up a VPN to increase security.

Answer (score 0):

Since your python based webserver is for home use only, you should block all incoming connections and allow only ones from your own Country/City.

You can do this using ipsets/iptables.

Answer (score 0):

Get a firewall for your computer running the webserver, banhammer the offending IP address.

If your webserver is only for devices in your house (on your network) to communicate with, there is likely a way to make it only visible from inside your network. My routers all hide computers connected to them from the rest of the internet, preventing most incoming connections.